# How to do return a dynamic object key in array.map()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular, typescript

**How to do return a dynamic object key in array.map()**

---

I'm just getting max value from a array by a object with using this below code which is works good.

```
Math.max.apply(Math, class.map(function (o) { return o.Students; }));
```

where, class is an `array` and Students is an `key` of that `array object`

---

But Whenever I need to get a maximum value, I need write that full code. So I planed to move that code to a common method as below.

```
 getMaxValue(array: any[], obj: key) {
      return  Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function (o) { 
               return o.key;  // Here I want return students objects
               }));   
           }
```

where,
I have passing a array and key(which is want to get the max value, like *students*). So whenever I want to get the max value I just call the method just like

```
 var maxOfStudents = getMaxValue(class, "Students");
```

---

***But I don't know how to return the `key` dynamically from a object in `array.map()`. how to do it?***

Comment: hmm... o[key] ?

Comment: String `key` instead of object and `o[key]` should do the trick.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash What will I do if I want two key's?

Comment: @RameshRajendran that's another question :)

Comment: @StanislavKvitash . yupe. I have asked that for a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719783/how-to-get-maximum-of-value-between-multiple-objects-from-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property using a string from an object.

```
return o[key];
```